# connection.quote(Time.now.utc.to_s(:db))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I was reading an [article about RapGenius's fall from grace](http://news.rapgenius.com/Rap-genius-founders-rap-genius-is-back-on-google-lyrics) when I came across this line of code:

```
connection.quote(Time.now.utc.to_s(:db))
```

It was in this context:

```
scope :not_locked, -> { where(locked_at: nil) }
scope :unscraped, -> { where(fetched: false).not_locked }

def Url.reserve_batch_for_scraping(limit)
  urls_subquery = unscraped.limit(limit).order(:id).select(:id).lock(true).to_sql
  db_time_now = connection.quote(Time.now.utc.to_s(:db))

  find_by_sql <<-SQL
    UPDATE urls SET locked_at = #{db_time_now}, updated_at = #{db_time_now}
    WHERE id IN (#{urls_subquery})
    RETURNING *
  SQL
end
```

What does `:db` do in the call to get the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone/to_s):

```
to_s(format = :default) public
```

> `:db` format outputs time in UTC;

This is the different output with & without the `:db` argument

```
>> Time.now.utc.to_s(:db)
=> "2014-01-07 20:21:32"
>> Time.now.utc.to_s()
=> "Tue Jan 07 20:21:39 UTC 2014"
```